# Two RewriteRule s Not Working together

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The result I need is:

```
http://mywebsite.co/company.php?title=company-name
```

should look like

```
http://mywebsite.co/company-name
```

And in the same way:

```
mywebsite.co/project.php?compname=compan-name&prjt=project-name
```

should look like

```
mywebsite.co/company-name/project-name
```

This is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /company.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=([A-Za-z0-9-]*)$
RewriteRule ^company\.php$ http://mywebsite.co/%1? [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^compname=([A-Za-z0-9-/]*)&prjt=([A-Za-z0-9-/]*)$ 
RewriteRule ^project\.php$ http://mywebsite.co/%1/%2? [L]
```

These two rules are working IF used individually. But if used together in one file, only one rule (`project.php`) is working. The required URL structure is coming for the second rule (`company.php`), but the content is empty (site layout, header and footer are coming).

Any help?

Comment: Rules are processed in order so the last catchall rule you have will be used.  What do you want to show in the browser? It seems you are trying to go the other way.

Comment: The result I need is http://mywebsite.co/company.php?title=company-name should look like
http://mywebsite.co/company-name & same way "mywebsite.co/project.php?compname=compan-name&prjt=project-name" should look like "mywebsite.co/company-name/project-name"  @PanamaJack

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question clearly. Do you want that to do a REDIRECT or are you wanting friendly URL's? Which version of the URL do you want to display in the browser?

Comment: Also you have both company.php and project.php as rules for all the 404/fake requests. You can't have both. Which file are you needing to direct the requests to.

Comment: I think both need Redirect & I want a friendly URLs. Thanks. @PanamaJack

Comment: Ok please answer my last question too.

Comment: Actually I see what you are trying to do. One sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /company\.php\?title=(.+)
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /project\.php\?compname=(.+)&prjt=(.+)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ project.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ company.php [L]
```

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Can you explain, not working? What Happens? Give me an example URL you are typing in the browser.

Comment: If I use your code, Urls are not Redirecting & content is also not showing.

Comment: **So what happens when you type in http ://mywebsite.co/company-name** with my code?

Comment: Using your given code. IF type "http://mywebsite.co/company-name" directly the page & content is coming good. & Project page is also working if directly typed "http://mywebsite.co/company-name/project-name". BUT my links are like " mywebsite.co/company.php?title=company-name" & "mywebsite.co/project.php?compname=compan-name&prjt=project-name" it is not redirecting & Not Working. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Can you try clearing your browser cache or try in another browser and check it.

Comment: Tested, Not Redirecting. IF typed directly http://mywebsite.co/company-name it is working But Not redirecting from http://mywebsite.co/company.php?title=company-name

Comment: Ok, I will try. I will inform you which code worked after its done. Thank you very much.

Comment: _ ' RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ company.php [L]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=([A-Za-z0-9-]*)$
 RewriteRule ^company.php$ http://mywebsite.co/%1 [2]? [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /project.php
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}
^compname=([A-Za-z0-9-/]*)&prjt=([A-Za-z0-9-/]*)$
 RewriteRule ^project.php$ http://mywebsite.co/%1/%2 [3]? [L] ' _   I altered my code like this, It worked. Thank you. @PanamaJack

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ company.php [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=([A-Za-z0-9-]*)$
RewriteRule ^company.php$ http://mywebsite.co/%1 [2]? [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^compname=([A-Za-z0-9-/]*)&prjt=([A-Za-z0-9-/]*)$
RewriteRule ^project.php$ http://mywebsite.co/%1/%2 [3]? [L]'
```

I altered my code like this. It worked. :)